# Telling if a Git commit is a Merge/Revert commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-hash

I am writing a script that requires checking whether a particular commit is a Merge/Revert commit or not, and I am wondering if there is a git trick for that.

What I came up with so far (and I definitely don't want to depend on the commit message here) is to check `HASH^2` and see if I don't get an error, is there a better way?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Figuring out if something is a merge is easy. That's all commits with more than one parent. To check for that, you can do, for example

```
$ git cat-file -p $commit_id
```

If there's more than one `parent' line in the output, you found a merge.

For reverts it's not as easy. Generally reverts are just normal commits that happen to apply the diff of a previous commit in reverse, effectively removing the changes that commit introduced. They're not special otherwise.

If a revert was created with `git revert $commit`, then git usually generates a commit message indication the revert and what commit it reverted. However, it's quite possible to do reverts in other ways, or to just change the commit message of a commit generated by `git revert`.

Looking for those generated revert commit message might already be a good enough heuristic for what you're trying to achieve. If not, you'd have to actually look through other commits, comparing their diffs against each other, checking if one is the exact reverse operation of another. But even that isn't a good solution. Often enough reverts are slightly different than just the reverse of the commit they're reverting, for example to accommodate for code changes that happened between the commit and the revert.

Comment: how do you get the branch that was merged?

Answer (score 28):

The following instruction will dump out **only** the parent hashes. Less filtering needed...

`git show --no-patch --format="%P" <commit hash>`

Answer (score 17):

The answer using `git cat-file` is using a git **"plumbing"** command, which is generally better for building scripts as the output format is not likely to change.  The ones using `git show` and `git rev-parse` may need to change over time as they are using [**porcelain**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git) commands.

The bash function I've been using for a long time uses `git rev-list`:

```
gitismerge () {
    local sha="$1"
    msha=$(git rev-list -1 --merges ${sha}~1..${sha})
    [ -z "$msha" ] && return 1
    return 0
}
```

The list of porcelain/plumbing commands can be found in the docs for the top level  [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) command.

This code uses [git-rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) with a specific [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) query `${sha}~1..${sha}` in a way that prints a SHA's second parent if it exists, or nothing if it is not present, which is the exact definition of a merge commit.

Specifically, `SHA~1..SHA` means *include commits that are reachable from SHA but exclude those that are reachable SHA~1, which is the first parent of SHA*.

The results are stored in $msha and tested for emptiness using bash `[ -z "$msha" ]` failing (returning 1) if empty, or passing (returning 0) if non-empty.

Comment: what do you mean with *porcelain*? what answer are you referring to exactly?

Comment: Hi @knocte I added some text to my answer with links, HTH.

Comment: thanks for the update; two more questions: what does `[ -z foo ]` actually do? I want to know this because I'm interested in using this but not in a bash script... also, what are the downsides&upsides of your solution compared to the `cat-file` one? cheers

Comment: Hi @knocte, I improved the answer and hopefully covered both of your questions.  The conciseness of the code is the real 'upside', which is just the spelling of the SHA~1..SHA revision specifier, which maps the output to a very sinple "empty vs. non-empty" bash test.   Note I also updated the answer with the extra "-1" option which further limits the output from 'git rev-list'

Comment: ``is_merge ()  { return $(( ! `git rev-list --no-walk --count --merges "$@"`)) } ``

Comment: @jthill nice, +1.  I hadn't seen --count.  Could also write `is_only_child() { return $(git rev-list --no-walk --count --merges "$@"); }`...

Comment: I found that this did not work. `git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`

Comment: @thill, I like your solution.  (I needed a semicolon after the `))` for it to compile in a bash script.)  Please consider posting as an answer.

Comment: @Chris "I found that this did not work...2.24.3" - do you mean the code in my answer or the code in the comments?

Comment: @qneill I am sorry, I have no idea; this is like 100 independent cross platform inconsistencies ago :-) My memory is hinting at `rev-list --no-walk --count --merges`, but I don't have a mac anymore (working from Windows/WSL now), so I can't test.

Answer (score 14):

I'm finding all answer over complicated and some even not reliable.
Especially if you want to do different actions for merge and regular commit.

IMO best solutions is to call `git rev-parse` using second parent expression `^2` and then check for an errors:

```sh
git rev-parse HEAD^2 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && echo "is merge" || echo "regular commit"
```

This works perfectly for me. Most of example above is just a decoration which just discards unwanted output.

And for windows `cmd` this works nicely too:

```
git rev-parse "HEAD^2" >nul 2>nul && echo is merge || echo regular commit
```

note quote characters

Answer (score 5):

One way to test for a merge commit:

```
$ test -z $(git rev-parse --verify $commit^2 2> /dev/null) || echo MERGE COMMIT
```

As for git revert commits, I agree with [@rafl](/users/54157/rafl) that the most realistic approach is to look for the revert message boilerplate in the commit message; if someone changed it, detecting so would be very involved.

Comment: what does `test -z` do exactly? the question doesn't ask for bashisms...

Comment: tests for emptiness, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096670/what-does-z-mean-in-bash

Comment: For what it's worth, "test" is not a bashism -- it should work with other POSIX-friendly shells, too. On Windows, you can use msysGit (by installing Git for Windows), or Cygwin, or the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way to find a commit's parents:

```
git show -s --pretty=%p <commit>
```

Use `%P` for full hash. This prints how many parents `HEAD` has:

```
git show -s --pretty=%p HEAD | wc -w
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works well for manual inspection of the result, but has a fatal flaw for scripting: the commit message itself could contain a line starting with "parent", and you might accidentally catch that, instead of the meta data at the top of the output.

A more reliable alternative is:

```sh
git show --summary <commit>
```

And check if a line starts with `Merge:`. This is similar to git cat-file, but it will prefix the commit message with spaces, so you can grep for it safely in a script:

```sh
git show --summary HEAD | grep -q ^Merge:
```

This will return 0 for merge commits, 1 for non-merge commits. Replace HEAD by your desired commit to test.

Example usage:

```
if git show --summary some-branch | grep -q ^Merge: ; then
    echo "some-branch is a merge"
fi
```

This works because the commit message itself is prefixed by 4 spaces, so even if it contained a line starting with "Merge:", it would look like     `Merge:..`, and the regex would not catch it. Note the `^` at the start of the regex, which matches the start of the line.

Comment: this seems like a pretty hacky solution to me, because if someone uses the word "Merge" in a normal (non-merge) commit, then you would have a **false positive**

Comment: @knocte that's what the caret (^) in the regular expression is for: it searches for Merge _at the start of a line_. The commit message is indented by a few spaces, so even if that contains Merge, it won't match. The contents of the diff itself (aside from being indented, as well) are not shown, courtesy of the --summary flag. I know it looks yucky, but that's Git :) this solution doesn't have false positives.

Comment: sure, but e.g. the top voted answer right now depends on exactly the same mechanism, it just doesn't mention the grep part. however, cat-file doesn't indent the commit message, so, there, you do end up with a false positive... anyway, it's only ugly if you're used to the porcelain part of git. this solution (and any other in this thread) fits just fine on the plumbing side.

Comment: how is using `git cat-file` grep? can you elaborate?

Comment: git cat-file just gives you text output, you still have to parse it for the "parent" line. Look at the answer text: "If there's more than one `parent' line in the output, you found a merge." In other words: grep. And if the commit message has a line starting with "parent", you can't (easily) do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the output of the following command is 1, that will indicate it is an individual commit. If not, it is a merge commit

```
git cat-file -p $commitID | grep -o -i parent | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether it's a merge commit,

```
# Use the FULL commit hash because -q checks if the entire line is matched.
git rev-list --merges --all | grep -qx <FULL_commit_hash>
echo $?    # 0 if it's a merge commit and non-zero otherwise
```

To check whether it's a revert commit, you'll have to go through the other answers.

Comment: ... which doesn't scale too well if your repo has hundreds of thousands of commits.