# Check if a branch has been merged to master and hasn't been reverted out

Tags: git

I would like to create a tool that will list out the names of feature branches that have been merged into a branch (e.g. master), but excluding branches whose merges have since been reverted.

For example:

```
   /--*--*--*--\                           feature
  /             \
------*--*-------*--*--*--*-------------*  master
                 ^     ^
                 |     | git revert -m1 abc1 (#abc2)
                 |       
                 | git merge --no-ff feature (#abc1)
```

I understand that `git branch --contains feature` will return `master`, and I understand why, but I would like to know if there is a simple-enough way to exclude branches that have since been reverted out.

If not, what would be optimal solution? Comparing diffs?

Comment: Good question, and if you try to merge again you get `Already up-to-date.`

Answer (score 1):

First, from "[How can I know in git if a branch has been already merged into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226976/6309)", you can check if your feature branch is part of `git branch --merged` or check `git merge-base` to find the merged commit.

Second, the question "[Telling if a Git commit is a Merge/Revert commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3824050/6309)" does warn us that a revert commit can be hard to find, and only advocate for the revert message boilerplate in the commit message.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of this, too. Relying on the boilerplate revert message just isn't robust enough for my taste. I'm thinking that the solution will involve comparing diffs of the feature branch against master but I guess that's error-prone too, particularly if there were merge conflicts.

Comment: @apancutt agreed. Although a 90%+ similarity between those two diffs would be a good tell for a revert commit.

Comment: I tried using `git diff -R | git patch-id` but didn't get usable results even in a trivial case.  It's possible with some additional filtering it would work in the non-merge conflict case though.

Answer (score 1):

Do the simple search which is

```
git log --grep="This reverts commit ${merge_sha}"
```

If they hand edited the commit message then you are stuck with something awful like

```
matchId=$(git diff  ${merge_sha}^! | grep -v -e "^diff --git" -e "^--- " -e "^+++ " -e "^index " | sha1sum

for sha in $(git revlist ${merge_sha}..HEAD)
do
  shaId=$(git diff  -R ${sha}^! | grep -v -e "^diff --git" -e "^--- " -e "^+++ " -e "^index " | sha1sum)
  if [ ${matchId} == ${shaId} ]
  then
      echo "${sha} might be a ninja revert of ${merge_sha}"
   fi
done
```

This could obviously be improved a lot to reverse the fields of some of the lines that I am excluding with grep currently.  You'd basically be re-implementing `git patch-id` but allowing it to have the a/b files all reversed (maybe there is an option to allow that already, but I don't know what it is)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to simply grep through the log:

```
git log | grep "^commit " | grep <commit-id>
```

- `git log` — shows the log of all the commits
- `grep "^commit "` — filters by commit ID (since they all start with "commit")
- `grep <commit-id>`— filter by just the commit you care about

*NOTE*—This may not work if git changes the commit ID.