# Sync github upstream with fork

Tags: git, github, git-fork

After a branch has been merged to `master` on my fork I want to automatically merge `master` into the upstream repo's `master`.
If I can't do this, can I automatically create a new pull request from my fork's master to upstream's master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [setup a post-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7925850/6309), trigger after creation of the merge commit.

That hook will have to [test if the commit made is a merge commit or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3824050/6309).
If it is, and if the current branch is `master`, then a simple `git push upstream` can proceed.
That is, if you are the owner of the upstream repo.

If not, you will have to:

- push your feature branch to origin
- [call the GitHub API to create a PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request).

Answer (score 1):

> After a branch has been merged to master on my fork I want to
>   automatically merge master into the upstream repo's master.

If you are not the owner of upstream repository, you can use pull request, but you can not do it automatically.

If you are the owner of upstream repository, you can use merge, but you can not do it automatically (you can use script for automatic, some thing likes this: https://github.com/pivotalsoftware/auto-merge-upstream).

But your wish is irrational. Why you don't commit directly to upstream, you don't need what called **automatic**, because the result is the same.

> If I can't do this, can I automatically create a new pull request from
>   my fork's master to upstream's master?

Of course.