# Is there a way to tell if a GIT commit is a merge?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is it possible to determine whether a commit (or md5hash value) is a "merge" from a developer branch to a parent branch? (i.e. master)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check from the git command , here is the so link that has the command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824050/telling-if-a-git-commit-is-a-merge-revert-commit

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just check how many parents it has:

```
git show --pretty=%ph --quiet some-brach-or-commit
```

If more than one parent shows up, it's a merge commit.

Comment: Thanks! So here is a problem, I think our repo has squash commits. I just checked one of our 'merge' commits and it only has one parent.... not sure why. (Developer branch getting merged to Master)

Comment: It is probably because it was a _squash_ merge.... and then you are out of luck because _to git_, that's not a real merge because there is no relation to the _other_ branch that was merged.

Comment: thanks @eftshift0 , that's what I feared :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use ether UI or `git log` on `master` that will show you a list of all the commits made to a repository and search for your commit

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was actually trying to ask if there was a way we can determine a commit is a 'merge' type commit :(