# Trigger jobs on a CI/CD pipeline on merge of the merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, merge-request

I am currently working on a CI/CD pipeline on gitlab. I have 5 different stages :

- install
- test
- package
- deploy
- cleanup

What I want to do is to trigger the cleanup jobs that clean the deployed dev instances of the application.

I tried few different options using gitlab `rules`, I tried to get the merged event using :

```
cleanup:graphql_ci:
  before_script: *graphql_before_script
  stage: cleanup
  script:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_STATE == "merged"'
```

But I found out that the $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_STATE variable is not a gitlab variable.
Is there any way to trigger a job on a merge request when the button of merge is clicked or something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to trigger a job on a merge request when the button of merge is clicked or something like this ?

There isn't really a *great* way to do this. Keep in mind that, when you merge a branch into another, this is basically just a normal git push action on the target branch.

Technically, it's possible to [use `git` to infer if a commit was a merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824050/telling-if-a-git-commit-is-a-merge-revert-commit), but GitLab doesn't expose this information in any predefined environment variable that you could use in a `rules:` definition.

One way you can *try* to do this, is by using a rule that identifies a merge commit by the merge commit message. *By default* merge commit messages will have the template that ends each git message with `See merge request %project_path&!%mr_iid%` so, commits usually look like this:

```
The commit message title, (usually the MR title)

This is the mr description

See merge request mygroup/mysubgroup/myproject!123
```

So, you could use this to write a rule that checks for this default message on the commit that gets made when merging an MR:

```
myjob:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /(.*)See merge request [\w\/\-\_]+!\d+$/
```

However, one caveat here is that the commit message for merges can be overridden, so this is just a best effort.

---

Another method would be to not use `rules:` but instead, process this requirement as part of the job itself. You could have the job effectively be a no-op if it's determined that the present and simply `exit 0` -- otherwise, allow the job script to continue if it *is* a merge commit.

For example, applying [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211450/5747944) (to which I don't make any assertions about its correctness/completeness), you can do something like this:

```yaml
.on_merge_commit:
  before_script:
    - |
      is_merge_commit=$(git rev-parse --verify "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"^2 2> /dev/null)
      
      if [[ -z "$is_merge_commit" ]]; then
         echo "not a merge commit, exiting" > /dev/stderr
         exit 0
      fi


myjob:
  extends: .on_merge_commit
  script:
    - echo "this message will only appear on merge commits"
```

---

## Cleaning up environments

> What I want to do is to trigger the cleanup jobs that clean the deployed dev instances of the application.

In your scenario, however, there is another option. When using GitLab's [environments features](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/), you can define a job to run whenever an environment is "stopped", to clean it up. GitLab also supports [stopping an environment when a merge request is merged or closed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#stop-an-environment-when-a-merge-request-is-merged-or-closed). This is part of GitLab's [review apps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/) methodology. In this way, you can make sure that your environments are cleaned up when an MR is merged or closed.

Using the example from the docs:

```yaml
deploy_review:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy a review app"
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    on_stop: stop_review
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

stop_review:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Remove review app"
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: manual
```

In your case, the `deploy_review` job is the job that deploys your application to your 'dev instances'. The `stop_review` job would be triggered when the merge request is closed or merged and you would define this job to clean the environment. The job names are just examples -- the important parts are the `environment:`, `environment:action`, and [`environment:on_stop`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environmenton_stop) keywords.